# Concatenation between data of two ports

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, pic, bit

I'm using pic18f4550 in which the size of it's port are 6 bits

I want to read and write a data of 8 bit.
what I did is writing data on (let say) port A and port C

what I want to do now, is to read all the 6 bits form port A and concatenate them with the first two bits of C in order to store the result in character which holds 8 bit
How can I do such concatenation?

in other words I want to do this char a =  PortA from(0-5) + portc from(0:1)?

Answer (score 0):

Just shift, mask and `OR` the bits together, e.g.

```
uint8_t a, b;

// ... read data from ports A and B into a, b ...

uint8_t c = (a << 2) | (b & 0x03); // shift a left by 2 bits and
                                   // OR with LS 2 bits of b
```